# Unable to upload blank file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload

I'm fairly new to .NET and just started learning .NET technology. I have written a code to upload a file. The code is as below

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 namespace WebApplication2
 {
public partial class FileUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

            if (fileExtension.ToLower() != ".doc" && fileExtension.ToLower() != ".docx")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Only Doc and Docx files are allowed";
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 2097152)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Limit of file size is 2MB";
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + FileUpload1.FileName)))
                    {
                        Label1.Text = "This is file already exists.";
                        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + FileUpload1.FileName));
                        Label1.Text = "File uploaded successfully";
                        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Please select a file to be uploaded";
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
}
```

All the scenarios are working fine. But when I'm trying to upload a blank file, its showing me message "Please select a file to be uploaded" just like I haven't selected anything. Is there any way to upload the blank file?

Comment: what do u mean by blank file ,means u uploading a file that doesnt have content?

Comment: yes, file having no content.

Comment: If the FileUpload control has no file, it is possible that the problem is in the client code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HasFile is:

```
public bool HasFile
{
    get
    {
        HttpPostedFile postedFile = this.PostedFile;
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            return (postedFile.ContentLength > 0);
        }
        return false;
   }
}
```

, it returns false for empty files. Create some workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice and I'm able to find the work around with this.

```
if (FileUpload1.FileContent.Length == 0 && FileUpload1.FileName != "")
```

The above criteria will tell us that user has selected a file which is totally empty.